# Xcode 13.2.1 SwiftUI 3 iOS 15.2: View with toolbar buttons get frozen when navigated from view with searchbar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Parent view has list with searchable functionality, trying to search for a recipe and then navigate to the child view that has toolbar with button, the child view get frozen when navigating from the searchbar, if I navigate from the normal list without searching in the parent view, everything works as expected, but when I try to search and then navigate, the child view get frozen, I tried:

- removing the toolbar and navigated from the searchbar, worked as expected.
- created empty toolbar in the child view without buttons, worked as expected.
- I have an old app that started having this issue, I created a new project to check if this issue happens only in my code, but no, this issue also happens in a new project with iOS 15.2 and Xcode 13.2.1.

I noticed that I started having this issue when I tried to release a new version with iOS 15.2, I suppose this is an iOS and SwiftUI issue but not sure how to work around on it.

Parent View:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RecipesView: View {
    
    @State private var recipes: [String] = ["Brownies", "Cake", "Bread", "Pan"]
    @State private var filteredRecipes: [String] = []
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.filteredRecipes, id: \.self) { recipe in
                    NavigationLink {
                        RecipeView(recipe: recipe)
                    } label: {
                        Text(recipe)
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: self.$searchText)
            .onChange(of: self.searchText, perform: { newValue in self.filter() })
            .onAppear { self.filter() }
        }
    }
    
    private func filter() {
        if self.searchText.isEmpty {
            self.filteredRecipes = self.recipes
        } else {
            self.filteredRecipes = self.recipes.filter {
                return ($0.lowercased().contains(self.searchText.lowercased()))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Child View:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RecipeView: View {
    
    var recipe: String
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text(self.recipe)
            }
            
            Section {
                Text("Another Text")
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    
                } label: {
                    Text("Edit")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did see your issue once, I think, and I thought it may be due to 
the `Autocorrection`. So I disable the Autocorrection, like this: 
`.searchable(text: self.$searchText).disableAutocorrection(true)`.
This seems to work, but then, removing that, still work now.
In other words I cannot replicate your issue anymore. All works well for me.
Xcode 13.2, tested on ios-15.2 device.

Comment: I tried to disable autocorrection as you mentioned but had no success, still having the issue :(